# Sorting array of objects by price (lowest to highest)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions

Below is some of the data that I'm currently working with while making a web app in React.js, right now I'm trying to sort the array of objects by price lowest to highest so that when a button is clicked the array is sorted and is displayed on the DOM from lowest to highest.

A couple of things I'm having to consider is that the prices are all comprised as strings with a '$' character as the first character (EX: '$18') and the second object in the arrays price is "Suggested Donation".

```
studios: [
  {
    name: "Whole Yoga",
    price: "$17.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Rino Yoga Social",
    price: "Suggested Donation"
  },
  {
    name: "Samadhi Yoga",
    price: "$20.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Corepower Yoga",
    price: "$25.00"
  },
  {
    name: "The River Yoga",
    price: "$20.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Endorphin Yoga",
    price: "$10.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Kindness Yoga",
    price: "$20.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Yoga High",
    price: "$15.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Freyja Project",
    price: "$22.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Kula Yoga",
    price: "$17.00"
  }
 ]
```

So far I used a while loop to remove the '$' character at the beginning of the string then used .replace() method to replace "Suggested Donation" with '00.00' and parseInt all the prices.

The issue I'm having now is that the new array of sorted prices have nothing to do with the original data (nothing linking them) so I'm just returning an array of sorted prices that I cant do anything with. Anyone have any ideas on how I should go about this?

```
priceFilter = () => {
    let newArr = []

    return this.props.studios.filter( studio => { 
      let price = studio.price;
      while(price.charAt(0) === '$') {
       price = price.substr(1);
      }
      price = price.replace('Suggested Donation', '00.00')
      let parsedPrice = parseInt(price);
      newArr.push(parsedPrice)
      return newArr.sort((a,b) => (a - b));
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. :)

```js
let studios = [{
    name: "Whole Yoga",
    price: "$17.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Rino Yoga Social",
    price: "Suggested Donation"
  },
  {
    name: "Samadhi Yoga",
    price: "$20.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Corepower Yoga",
    price: "$25.00"
  },
  {
    name: "The River Yoga",
    price: "$20.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Endorphin Yoga",
    price: "$10.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Kindness Yoga",
    price: "$20.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Yoga High",
    price: "$15.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Freyja Project",
    price: "$22.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Kula Yoga",
    price: "$17.00"
  }
];
console.log("Unsorted", studios);

studios.sort(({
  price: a
}, {
  price: b
}) => {
  //parseFloat will be Nan if it cannot parse the string into a number
  //the only problem here is that any non int string will turn into 0
  a = parseFloat(a.slice(1), 10) || 0;
  b = parseFloat(b.slice(1), 10) || 0;

  return a - b;
});

console.log("Sorted", studios);
```

Comment: Note parseInt ignores decimals

Answer (score 1):

Convert your values to numbers. Based on your code your suggest price should be 0, so we use that if the price does not start with a dollar sign `'$'`

```js
const studios = [
  {
    name: "Whole Yoga",
    price: "$17.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Rino Yoga Social",
    price: "Suggested Donation"
  },
  {
    name: "Samadhi Yoga",
    price: "$20.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Corepower Yoga",
    price: "$25.00"
  },
  {
    name: "The River Yoga",
    price: "$20.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Endorphin Yoga",
    price: "$10.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Kindness Yoga",
    price: "$20.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Yoga High",
    price: "$15.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Freyja Project",
    price: "$22.00"
  },
  {
    name: "Kula Yoga",
    price: "$17.00"
  }
 ]

priceFilter = (vals) => {
  return vals.sort((a,b) => {
    const aPrice = a.price[0] === '$' ? parseFloat(a.price.slice(1,-1)) : 0;
    const bPrice = b.price[0] === '$' ? parseFloat(b.price.slice(1,-1)) : 0;
    return aPrice - bPrice;
  });
}

console.log(priceFilter(studios));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom sort with `Array.prototype.sort` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
const compare = (a, b) => {
  const aPrice = Number(a.price.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));
  const bPrice = Number(b.price.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));

  return aPrice - bPrice
};


const sortedStudios = this.props.studios.sort(compare);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a function for getting the value for sorting and then take the delta as redsult for the sorting method.

```js
const getValue = ({ price }) => +price.slice(1) || 0;

var studios = [{ name: "Whole Yoga", price: "$17.00" }, { name: "Rino Yoga Social", price: "Suggested Donation" }, { name: "Samadhi Yoga", price: "$20.00" }, { name: "Corepower Yoga", price: "$25.00" }, { name: "The River Yoga", price: "$20.00" }, { name: "Endorphin Yoga", price: "$10.00" }, { name: "Kindness Yoga", price: "$20.00" }, { name: "Yoga High", price: "$15.00" }, { name: "Freyja Project", price: "$22.00" }, { name: "Kula Yoga", price: "$17.00" }];

studios.sort((a, b) => getValue(a) - getValue(b));

console.log(studios);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it covers the case of the price being  "Suggested Donation"

Comment: @weilandia, sorry didn't see this. please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to sort objects by price instead of sorting prices:

```js
const studios = [{"name":"Whole Yoga","price":"$17.00"},{"name":"Rino Yoga Social","price":"Suggested Donation"},{"name":"Samadhi Yoga","price":"$20.00"},{"name":"Corepower Yoga","price":"$25.00"},{"name":"The River Yoga","price":"$20.00"},{"name":"Endorphin Yoga","price":"$10.00"},{"name":"Kindness Yoga","price":"$20.00"},{"name":"Yoga High","price":"$15.00"},{"name":"Freyja Project","price":"$22.00"},{"name":"Kula Yoga","price":"$17.00"}];

const parsePrice = x => parseFloat(x.replace(/^\$/, '')) || 0
const sortedStudios = studios
  .slice()
  .sort((a, b) => parsePrice(a.price) - parsePrice(b.price))

console.log(sortedStudios)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone! This solution worked for me.

```
priceFilter = () => {
    let ordered = studios.sort((a, b) => (a.price > b.price) ? 1 : -1);
    let lastElement = ordered.pop();
    return ordered.unshift(lastElement);
  }
```